# How to show that all power in an RC circuit is delivered to the resistor

Tags: power, math, theory

I am new to electronics and I've been working my way through the Art of Electronics. I've have been able to complete all the exercises up to this point but I have been struggling on this one. Right before the question the book shows how to calculate the power consumed in an RC circuit using P=Re(**VI***). I followed this part and now the exercise is asking to show that the power is entirely consumed by the resistor. I have included the question below and explain my reasoning.

The book gives
$$P=Re(VI^*)=\frac{V_0^2R}{R^2+(1/\omega^2C^2)}$$

Exercise 1.28. Show that all the average power delivered to the
preceding circuit winds up in the resistor. Do this by computing
the value of V<sup>2</sup>/R.

[image: Circuit for the question]

So first step would be to find current which I determined to be
$$I=\frac{V_0(R+j(1/\omega C))}{R^2+(1/\omega C)^2}$$

Next would be to determine the voltage drop across the resistor.
$$V_R=IR=\frac{V_0R(R+j(1/\omega C))}{R^2+(1/\omega C)^2}$$

Now the nightmare of squaring this begins but a step to simplify the work beforehand would be to factor the denominator.
$$V_R=IR=\frac{V_0R(R+j(1/\omega C))}{(R+j(1/\omega C))(R-j(1/\omega C))}=\frac{V_0R}{R-j(1/\omega C)}$$

Now finally to compute V<sup>2</sup>/R.

$$V^2/R=\left(\frac{V_0R}{R-j(1/\omega C)}\right)^2/R=\frac{V_0^2R}{(R-j(1/\omega C))^2}$$

Which is not equal to the answer obtained from Re(**VI***), even after further simplifcation. I have also tried this without factoring the denominator and also didn't end up with the right answer. There seems to be an imaginary part that I can't get rid of and if I try taking the real part of V<sub>R</sub> for the calculation that also doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to prove that none of the energy is dissipated in the capacitor so it must dissipate in the resistor.

Comment: You may use the well known formula (a  - b)^2 = a^2 -2ab + b^2 at the denominator. Remember that j^2 = -1.

Comment: Note that it is not \$V^{2}\$ but it is the magnitude \$|V|^{2}\$. This is because \$V I^*\$ becomes \$S=V V^* /R\$ when replacing I using ohms law. \$VV^{*}\$ gives the magnitude squared (you should see to prove this yourself).

Comment: @imthegman55 thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Voltage divider:
$$\small V_R =\frac{V_0 R}{R-jX_C} $$
Magnitude of voltage across \$\small R\$  :
$$\small \mid V_R\mid =\frac{V_0 R}{\mid R-jX_C\mid}=\frac{V_0 R}{\sqrt {R^2 +X_C^2}} $$
Power dissipated by \$\small R\$ :
$$\small P=\frac{\mid V_R\mid^2}{R}=\frac{ V_0^2 R}{{{R^2 +X_C^2}}} $$